# Get min and max value in single query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregate

Considering the following Documents in "Words":

```
[{
  _id: 1,
  usages: 2,
  word: "Name"
}, {
  _id: 2,
  usages: 1,
  word: "Street"
}, {
  _id: 3,
  usages: 1,
  word: "House"
}, {
  _id: 4,
  usages: 3,
  word: "Table"
}, {
  _id: 5,
  usages: 3,
  word: "Bread"
}, {
  _id: 6,
  usages: 4,
  word: "Door"
}]
```

How can i get all the records where the number of usages is the lowest or highest? Lowest should return id 2 and 3(and their word), highest should return id 6 with its word.

I need to aggregate this data into a random amount of lowest/highest records (50 to be exact) so it needs to be an aggregate.

It should be a single lookup, so the min/max cannot be found using another query with $max or $min.

The MongoDB version is 3.4.7, Mongoose version 5.0.0-rc1. Mongoose solution not requred since I can use a raw query. (It is preferred however!)

Example:

```
Words.aggregate([ 
  { 
    $match: { _
      usages: { WHAT_SHOULD_I_HAVE_HERE }
    }
  }, { 
    $sample: { 
      size: 50 
    } 
  }
])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

[`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) will give you the two lowest and highest value for the `usages` and you can easily [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) through them using [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "minUsages": [{ "$sort": { "usages": -1 } }],
    "maxUsages": [{ "$sort": { "usages": 1 } }]
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "lowestUsages": {
      "$arrayElemAt": ["$minUsages", 0]
    },
    "highestUsages": {
      "$arrayElemAt": ["$maxUsages", 0]
    }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "minUsages": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$minUsages",
        "as": "minUsage",
        "cond": {
          "$eq": ["$$minUsage.usages", "$lowestUsages.usages"]
        }
      }
    },
    "maxUsages": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$maxUsages",
        "as": "maxUsage",
        "cond": {
          "$eq": ["$$maxUsage.usages", "$highestUsages.usages"]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Or you can simply do this with `find` query as well

```
const minUsage = await db.collection.find({}).sort({ "usages": -1 }).limit(1)
const maxUsage = await db.collection.find({}).sort({ "usages": 1 }).limit(1)

const minUsages = await db.collection.find({ "usages": { "$in": [minUsages[0].usages] } })
const maxUsages = await db.collection.find({ "usages": { "$in": [maxUsages[0].usages] } })
```

Take a look [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LP-lP4fvtLb)

Comment: Your aggregation works perfectly! Although you still added a method with 2 or 4 queries. Would you argue that the find method is faster then the aggregate?

Answer (score 0):

Given the following collection *MyCollection* data:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("ob1"), "value" : 17 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("ob2"), "value" : 99 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("ob3"), "value" : 35 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("ob4"), "value" : 46 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("ob5"), "value" : 12 }
```

You can perform the following query:

```
db.MyCollection.aggregate([
   { "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "max_val": { "$max": "$value" },
      "min_val": { "$min": "$value" }
   }}
]);
```

And get:

```
{ "_id" : null, "max_val" : 99, "min_val" : 12 }
```