# Mongo query min max excluding match condition

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a following pairModel collection schema :

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afaf31c8e7cd4d7e5675f17"),
    "trans_id" : 2910372,
    "fill_qty" : 3275466,
    "fill_price" : 610600,
    "fill_flags" : 2,
    "currencyPair" : "BTC-INR",
    "lastModifiedDate" : 1526395676478,
    "__ds" : {
        "_v" : 1
    },
    "ds_key" : "jh7skpq6-1lcoebwn5j3"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afaf3158e7cd4d7e5675e6d"),
    "trans_id" : 2910369,
    "fill_qty" : 276777,
    "fill_price" : 610600,
    "fill_flags" : 2,
    "currencyPair" : "BTC-INR",
    "lastModifiedDate" : 1526395669729,
    "__ds" : {
        "_v" : 1
    },
    "ds_key" : "jh7skkip-1pomnhe1sv0"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afaf30f8e7cd4d7e5675dfe"),
    "trans_id" : 2910366,
    "fill_qty" : 180150,
    "fill_price" : 610600,
    "fill_flags" : 2,
    "currencyPair" : "BTC-INR",
    "lastModifiedDate" : 1526395663092,
    "__ds" : {
        "_v" : 1
    },
    "ds_key" : "jh7skfec-16my2i58gl3"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afa7ea48e7cd4d7e55f0a15"),
    "trans_id" : 2907344,
    "fill_qty" : 6895,
    "fill_price" : 610600,
    "fill_flags" : 2,
    "currencyPair" : "BTC-INR",
    "lastModifiedDate" : 1526365860103,
    "__ds" : {
        "_v" : 1
    },
    "ds_key" : "jh7atn9j-22lylcn1u72"
}
]
```

and below is my query:

```
pairModel.aggregate([
        {
            '$match': {
                'lastModifiedDate': {'$exists': true, '$ne': null, '$gt': lt24hrTS, '$lt': nowTS}
            }
        },
        {
            '$group': {
                '_id': null,
                '24hoursHigh': {'$max': '$fill_price'},
                '24hoursLow': {'$min': '$fill_price'},
                "volume": { "$sum": "$fill_qty"},
                "lastTradedRate": { "$last": "$fill_price"},
                "firstTradedRate": { "$first": "$fill_price"},
            }

        },
        { "$sort": { "lastModifiedDate": 1 } }
        ])
```

which is giving me low-high for `fill_price`, `firstTradedRate` and volume for given `lastModifiedDate` match condition. Now my problem is, I want to takeout min-max calculation out of match condition. i.e it should give me min-max for `fill_price` irrespective of lastModifiedDate condition.

Complete data can be queried easily with two different queries, but can above aggregate query be modified to meet all conditions in single query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get min and max value in single query in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50900220/get-min-and-max-value-in-single-query-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different queries is probably the way to go but if you like to do in aggregation pipeline you can make use of [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) in 3.6 version.

Basically you are running multiple aggregation pipeline queries inside facet stage followed by concatenation of results.

Also, spotted some issues with your code and fixed it.

```
pairModel.aggregate([{
  "$facet":{
    "lastfirst":[
      {"$match":{"lastModifiedDate":{"$exists":true,"$ne":null,'$gt':lt24hrTS,'$lt': nowTS}}},
      {"$sort":{"lastModifiedDate":1}},
      {"$group":{
        "_id":null,
        "volume":{"$sum":"$fill_qty"},
        "lastTradedRate":{"$last":"$fill_price"},
        "firstTradedRate":{"$first":"$fill_price"}
      }}
   ],
   "maxmin":[
     {"$group":{
       "_id":null,
       "AllTimeHigh":{"$max":"$fill_price"},
       "AllTimeLow":{"$min":"$fill_price"}}
     }
    ]
  }
},
 {"$unwind":"$lastfirst"},
 {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":{"$mergeObjects":["$lastfirst", {"$arrayElemAt":["$maxmin", 0]}]}}
}])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I tried above code, but it is giving me following error - `MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$mergeObjects'
`. I am using v3.4.16

Comment: Yw. You will need 3.6 version to use mergeObjects. Replace the `$mergeObjects` with `{
    "$arrayToObject":{
      "$concatArrays":[
        {"$objectToArray":"$lastfirst"},
        {"$objectToArray": {"$arrayElemAt":["$maxmin", 0]}}
      ]
    }
  }` for 3.4 version.

Comment: Learned a new thing - `$facet`  from your answer